# display filename followed by content without interaction

Tags: filenames, text

My program writes it state to few files every 30 seconds or so (overwrites) and I would like to look at them with the filenames displayed like "more" does. Like:

```
$ echo 1234 > test00
$ echo 5678 > test01
$ ls
test00  test01
$ more *
::::::::::::::
test00
::::::::::::::
1234
::::::::::::::
test01
::::::::::::::
5678
```

For "more" you have to press space to get next file.

- What I want is the filenames before content in some way
- I tried "tail", but have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, 
  Can write a small program but I’m wondering if any standard unix program can do this ( display name of file, followed by content of file ) without further user interaction as with "more"

Comment: You had to ctrl-c? Just do `tail` without `-f`. It will display the last 10 lines in each file and the filenames.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the output from `more` is acceptable as it is, just pipe it through `cat`:

```
more * | cat
```

That will do away with the "more" prompts.

Or you can get a bit more control over the display using `printf` in a one-liner:

```
for fn in *; do printf "::::::\n$fn\n:::::\n"; cat "$fn"; done
```

or as script:

```
for fn in $*; 
do 
   printf "vvvvvvvvvv\n$fn\n^^^^^^^^^^\n"
   cat "$fn"
done
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do a few things.

`head` and `tail` are both spec'd to display the first/last ten lines of a file by default - but if called w/ multiple arguments will do that for all and display the filenames for each. And, of course, for each, you can use the `-n[num]` argument to specify a number of lines other than the default ten that you would like to display. I assume your CTRL-C problem was related to the `-f` option - which would instruct `tail` to follow a file - you probably should just leave that out.

Another thing you might do - which will result in output a little different than in the question, but which you might still like, is...

```
grep -F '' ./*files
```

`grep` is also spec'd to display the filename for its matches when it is given multiple filename arguments - but `grep` does it at the head of every line. Like

```
seq 10 >nums.txt; grep -F '' /dev/null nums.txt
```

...which prints...

```
nums.txt:1
nums.txt:2
nums.txt:3
nums.txt:4
nums.txt:5
nums.txt:6
nums.txt:7
nums.txt:8
nums.txt:9
nums.txt:10
```

...and highlighted on my terminal. The `/dev/null` thing is just a little trick to force the multiple file arg behavior even when working with only a single file, and `grep -F ''` matches every line - even blank ones.

And here's `head /dev/null nums.txt`:

```
==> /dev/null <==

==> nums.txt <==
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

`tail`'s output is identical in this case - but, again, both utilities only print so many lines of a file.

With the latest version of GNU `sed` you can use the `F` command like:

```
sed -s 1F ./*files
```

...or if you wanted a little border around the filename...

```
sed -se '1!b;i\\n---' -e 'F;i\---\n' nums.txt
```

...which does like...

```
---
nums.txt
---

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Or if you wanted to get adventurous you could do...

```
tar -c ./*files | tr -s \\0 | cut -d '' -f1,2,13 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

...but that's probably not practical.

Comment: Gotta love the simplicity of `sed -s 1F *files`...

Comment: @don_crissti - it can come in handy - especially in that it takes addresses. You can print the name on any line you choose. But not all linux distributions carry it yet, I guess - this and `-z` are still considered new of an *unstable* version by some distros I think. Or, that's what I've been told by others on a few occasions when I've suggested it. I've been using `-z` for probably a year I think - I dunno when it was released.

Comment: @don_crissti - there's nothing wrong with any of that - I just get used to doing things a certain way. Also, I find I learn more if I try harder. I use that stuff for fun a lot - and it helps me to learn how to do it myself as well - like what makes things tick. But if I always used `-H` I wouldn't know what weird stuff I could do with an EOF. So in the answers I like to keep it portable - partly because somebody may not be able to follow along otherwise, but mostly because I wouldn't learn anything writing it otherwise. `tar...|sed -z` was how I learned to do the impractical thing above.

Comment: Good suggestion to use `head`/`tail` - in addition to being easy to remember it's "safer" too (insofar as it won't flood your terminal if you accidentally try to display a massive file).

Answer (score 4):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print "::::\n"FILENAME"\n::::"}1' *
```

Answer (score 2):

The `cat` replacement [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) provides a really nice view of the contents of multiple files, with file names, separators, and line numbers:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1234 > test00

$ printf '%s\n' 5 67 8 > test01

$ bat test*
───────┬───────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: test00
───────┼───────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ 1234
───────┴───────────────────────────────────────
───────┬───────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: test01
───────┼───────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ 5
   2   │ 67
   3   │ 8
───────┴───────────────────────────────────────
```